# Resolving Missing Variable on Django Form

Tags: python, django, forms, payment-gateway, saleor

I'm restructuring an e-commerce that is using saleor 1.0. What I'm trying to achieve is reducing the redundancy in the steps to make a payment on an item. The architecture for checkout/payment for saleor 1.0 requires the customer from the payment page to go to a separate page to select payment a type (e.g. stripe, braintree, razor etc) using a radio button and then submit that selection which then processes the order and goes to the confirmation page.

**OBJECTIVE:**

What I'm trying to do is remove the step of sending the customer to a page to select their payment type, but rather include that option on the payment page, which i feel makes the experience more seamless.

**ISSUE:**

When including stripe to the payment page, I am receiving an error message which is displayed on the page:

> << MISSING VARIABLE "form.payment_method_id.as_hidden" >>

Also, stripe appears to be functioning, but when i submit credit card information i'm not redirected to the confirmation page.

**Payment.html** - the syntax commented is what shipped with saleor:

```
{% block paymentcontent %}
  <div class="row checkout">
    <div class="col-lg-10 m-auto checkout__payment">
      {% if order.user == user or not order.is_fully_paid %}
        {% if not order.is_fully_paid and order.billing_address %}
          {% if waiting_payment %}
            <h1>
              {% trans "Payment pending" context "Payment details title" %}
            </h1>
            <form method="post" action="{% url 'order:cancel-payment' token=order.token %}" class="checkout-form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <p>{% blocktrans trimmed context "Payment pending text" %}
                We are currently waiting for an external service to authorize
                your payment for this order.
              {% endblocktrans %}</p>
              <p>{% trans "Current status:" context "Payment status text" %}
                <br>
                <span class="label label-default">
                {{ waiting_payment.get_charge_status_display }}
                </span>
              </p>
              <p>{%  blocktrans trimmed context "Payment pending text" %}
                Unless you are absolutely sure that the process will not complete
                (for example you have closed the browser window before paying),
                you should wait before attempting a new payment.
                Please be warned that if you try again and the previous
                transaction succeeds you might end up being charged twice.
              {% endblocktrans %}</p>
              {% bootstrap_form waiting_payment_form %}
              <button type="submit" class="btn danger">
                {% trans "I understand, allow me to pay again" context "Payment pending action" %}
              </button>
            </form>
          {% elif payment_form %}

              {% include 'order/payment/stripe.html' %}

{#            <h1>#}
{#              {% blocktrans trimmed context "Payment details title" %}#}
{#                Pay for order {{ order }}#}
{#              {% endblocktrans %}#}
{#            </h1>#}
{#            {% include 'order/_ordered_items_table.html' %}#}


{#         <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-start">#}
{#            <h3>#}
{#              <b>{% trans "Choose payment method" %}</b>#}
{#            </h3>#}
{#            <div class="checkout__payment-form">#}
{#              <form method="post" action="{% url "order:payment" token=order.token %}" class="payment-form radio">#}
{#                {% csrf_token %}#}
{#                {% for choice in payment_form.gateway %}#}
{#                  <div class="radio checkout__payment-form__choice">#}
{#                    <label>#}
{#                      <div class="card card-default">#}
{#                        <div class="card-body">#}
{#                          <strong>#}
{#                            {{choice}}#}
{#                          </strong>#}
{#                        </div>#}
{#                      </div>#}
{#                    </label>#}
{#                  </div>#}
{#                {% endfor %}#}
{#                {% block form_submit %}#}
{#                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">#}
{#                    {% trans "Proceed to payment" context "Payment details primary action" %}#}
{#                  </button>#}
{#                {% endblock %}#}
{#              </form>#}
{#            </div>#}
{#          {% else %}#}
{#            <p>{% trans "You've authorized transaction. Order is in processing" context "Payment details text" %}</p>#}


          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endif %}
{#      </div>#}




      {% include 'order/_ordered_items_table.html' %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock paymentcontent %}
```

**stripe.html**

```
{% block forms %}

  <form method="POST" id="payment-form" {% if form.action %} action="{{ form.action }}"{% endif %} novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" id='cardholder-name' name="cardholder-name" placeholder="Cardholder Name" required/>
    </div><!-- form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div id="card-element" class="stripe" style="padding-top: .55rem;"></div>
    </div><!-- form-group -->
    <button id="card-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
      {% trans "Place your order" context "Payment form primary action" %}
    </button>
    <div class="outcome">
      <div class="error"></div>
    </div>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if form.errors or form.non_field_errors %}
      <blockquote>
        {% for non_field_error in form.non_field_errors %}
          {{ non_field_error }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% for error in form.errors %}
          {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
      </blockquote>
      <a class="btn" href="{% url "order:details" token=payment.order.token %}">
        {% trans "Change payment" context "Payment form (Stripe) secondary action" %}
      </a>
    {% endif %}
    {{ form.payment_method_id.as_hidden }}
  </form>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
stripe = Stripe('{{ client_token }}');
var options = {
  fonts:[{cssSrc: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato',}]
};
var elements = stripe.elements(options);

var cardElement = elements.create('card', {
  classes: {
    base: 'form-control',
  },
  style: {
    base: {
      iconColor: '#333333',
      color: '#333333',
      fontFamily: '"Lato", sans-serif',
      '::placeholder': {
        color: '#d3d1d0',
        fontWeight: 300,
      },
    },
  }
});
cardElement.mount('#card-element');

var cardholderName = document.getElementById('cardholder-name');
var cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
var payment_method_id = document.getElementById('id_payment_method_id');
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

cardButton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  stripe.createPaymentMethod('card', cardElement, {
    billing_details: {name: cardholderName.value}
  }).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Show error in payment form
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      errorElement.classList.add('visible');
    } else {
      // Otherwise send paymentMethod.id to your server (see Step 2)
      payment_method_id.value = result.paymentMethod.id;
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
</script>
{% endblock forms %}
```